# Main use and advantage of Delegate?

Tags: .net, delegates

What is the main use of delegate and their main advantages??
we can also use simple methods in place of delegate,then why we use delegate??

Comment: http://www.google.com?q=c%23+delegates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of great uses of delegates, but one important benefit over a simple method is the ability to [close](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) over the environment.  So, without delegates or lambdas or some other similar feature, it's impossible to write code like

```
public delegate int PartiallyApplied(int b);

public static PartiallyApplied CurriedAdd(int a)
{
    return delegate (int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    };
}
```

You may be wondering why closing over the environment is useful.  One important use case is [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query).  A simple method that keeps only the elements of a sequence that are within a certain range is

```
public IEnumerable<int> WithinRange(this IEnumerable<int> seq, int lower, int upper)
{
    return select n from seq where n >= lower && n < upper;
}
```

(As this is demo code, it is missing error checking and other features of production code)

This code desugars to

```
public IEnumerable<int> WithinRange(this IEnumerable<int> seq, int lower, int upper)
{
    return seq.Where(n => n >= lower && n < upper);
}
```

which uses a lambda that closes over the `lower` and `upper` local variables.  Without delegates or lambdas, it would be impossible to achieve such clear and succinct code for this kind of task.

Answer (score 1):

Delegates are function pointers done right.

You can 'hot swap' functions in and out at run-time.  You can pass them to other functions.